# What was Daniel Craig's character's name?

Tags: character, layer-cake

In the movie [Layer Cake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layer_Cake_%28film%29), Daniel Craig stars as a drug dealer. His name is not mentioned throughout the movie. He was even credited as "XXXX", he also said near the end, that if you knew his name, you would be as smart as him.

Anybody here has any idea about what his name was in the movie?

Comment: It‘s either Carey Lake or Lake Carey, if the name could be an anagram of (Layer Cake) the movie title.

Comment: If I were to guess, I'd like the idea of an anagram to "Layer Cake", at the very beginning of the movie, we see Daniel Craig leaving his house, with "Layer Cake" written on his door.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The character played by Daniel Craig, had no name in the movie. The movie, is based on a book of the same name [Layer Cake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layer_Cake_%28novel%29), and the protagonist (character played by Daniel Craig) has no name there too. He is ***Anonymous*** in the book.

If you read this [interview](http://www.bbc.co.uk/films/2004/09/17/matthew_vaughn_layer_cake_interview.shtml) of the director, Matthew Vaughan, you would know that they gave a name to this *anonymous* character, for the movie. Quoting the below part from that interview

> **It's an interesting character for him to play, isn't it? This man with
>   no name...**
>
> In the book he's just anonymous. But in the script it's really weird.
>   We didn't want to give him a name, but you have to call him something
>   in the script, so he became "XXXX". The last line of the book is the
>   last line of the movie. The studio wanted to cut it, but I told them
>   it was really important. The fact that he doesn't have a name is what
>   makes him so different. He's Clint Eastwood, riding in on a horse, he
>   doesn't give anything away. He's a chameleon.

Comment: Wow, so no matter how hard we try to find out. We'll come up with nothing since he really has no name, huh?

Comment: Yup, that is how the author wanted it to be :)

Comment: Bugger. It would have been really bad-ass if someone was able to find out. Lol.

Comment: @user2028096 *"Wow, so no matter how hard we try to find out. We'll come up with nothing since he really has no name"* - Well yeah, what other impression did you get from his name not even mentioned in the credits?

Answer (score -4):

I think his name, or at least handle is King. At the end, his main partner says, "the king is dead, long live the king." Plus, Temple told him he would be in his place some day and he was the king.